# change separate element style on focus on other element

Tags: html, css

How to make it work?
HTML

```css
#nav input[type=text]:focus ~ #two {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=nav>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
</div>
<div id="two">Two jfjsoijfoisoivnosnovdnsnnoivnoinsionvonoiniso</div>
```

I think the problem is due to the separate `div` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. It's only possible if the element is a sibling or a child of the `:focus`.

Either use Javascript, or put put the div inside the nav (which might not be what you're looking for if you can't change your DOM tree).

```css
#nav input[type=text]:focus~#two {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=nav>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
  <div id="two">Two jfjsoijfoisoivnosnovdnsnnoivnoinsionvonoiniso</div>
</div>
```

Pure Javascript :

```js
var navbar = document.getElementById('nav')

navbar.addEventListener('focusin', toggleClass);
navbar.addEventListener('focusout', toggleClass);

function toggleClass() {
  document.querySelector('.two').classList.toggle('redColor');
}
```

```css
.redColor {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id=nav>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
</div>
<div class="two">Two jfjsoijfoisoivnosnovdnsnnoivnoinsionvonoiniso</div>
```

Comment: How to make it work then, what changes?

Comment: This is a relevant article that explains child and sibling selectors, complains about the missing functionality that the OP needs and demonstrates some jQuery patterns that solve this: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: @Lessey by either changing your dom, or by using js/jquery. I gave you both solutions, and a pure Js solution.

Comment: I tried pure js way and it didn't worked. @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: @Lessey as you can see in my example above, it works. Please make sure that your second div is a class and not an id, and that you have the right css class.

Comment: I did the same I used class not id but still it didn't work. @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: @Lessey create a small example in a jsfiddle or something, I can't guess :)

Comment: <div id="nav">
<ul>
<li><div class="search-container">
<form action="/action_page.php">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search Quora" name="search">
</form>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#user"><i class="fas fa-user-circle fa-lg"></i></a></li>
<li>
<a href="#lang"><i class="fas fa-globe fa-lg"></i></a>
</li>
<li>
<button class="add">Add Question</button>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="two"><p>How are you?</p>
 <p>Are you doing good?</p>
 <p>You will be fine.</p>
 <p>Everything will be alright.</p>
 ddnnfdnffff
 </div>
</div>

Comment: The above CSS code is any problem? @IslamElshobokshy

Comment: @Lessey it does work https://jsfiddle.net/nk3tcrhb/

Comment: Mine still not working, the js file is correctly linked. Anyway, this is what I was looking for. @IslamElshobokshy

Answer (score 2):

```css
#nav:focus-within ~ #two {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" />
</div>
<div id="two">Two jfjsoijfoisoivnosnovdnsnnoivnoinsionvonoiniso</div>
```

You can achieve this with `:focus-within` selector

Comment: This is wrong https://jsfiddle.net/tp9m76vn/, using this, if the `nav` contains more than one element, then the focus will happen on all of them.

Comment: No, it's not...clearly it works

Comment: @Paulie_D as I said, if the nav contains more than one element then all of them will be used. Not specifically the `input[type=text]`  the OP asked for.

Comment: ...but the OP **doesn't** have more than one element.

Comment: @Paulie_D seeing how he specifically asked for `input[type=text]` one assumes he wants only those.

Comment: This work if we have one element but I specifically asked for `input[type=text]` element as said by @IslamElshobokshy Is there any other way?

Comment: You can *assume* but to say that this is *wrong* is invalid.

Answer (score -1):

Css can't parse Dom tree like jquery, So it can't parse parent element.

`~` operator only work if your element exist in same depth.

```
<div id=nav>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search">
    <div id="two">Two jfjsoijfoisoivnosnovdnsnnoivnoinsionvonoiniso</div>
</div>
```

Comment: So how to make it work?

Comment: @VickyP, your id is wrong because in the question it is missing too, `id="nav"`